# Does anyone know where i can find some training on WebFOCUS?

Tags: webfocus

There are some webpages on commands etc I found online but would you happen to know where there could be videos or better described pages on how using the data in the system to run queries, commands, syntax, build reports, building equations in your reports to use the data.

There is a technical library by the info center of Webfocus but it only lists the commands. I am not sure how and where to use them. Some of the commands seem intuitive but I dont know how to properly use the language.

None

Answer (score 0):

There is a small video library located here: https://webfocusinfocenter.informationbuilders.com/wfappent/video.html

There is a lot of fragmenting with IBI though, and there are different things that work on different versions. What version of WebFOCUS are you on?